# How to skip an unknown number of empty lines before header on pandas.read_csv?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, file-io, data-import

I want to read a dataframe from a csv file where the header is not in the first line. For example:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import io

In [3]: temp=u"""#Comment 1
   ...: #Comment 2
   ...: 
   ...: #The previous line is empty
   ...: Header1|Header2|Header3
   ...: 1|2|3
   ...: 4|5|6
   ...: 7|8|9"""

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="|", comment="#", 
   ...:                  skiprows=4).dropna()

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   Header1  Header2  Header3
0        1        2        3
1        4        5        6
2        7        8        9

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

The problem with the above code is that I don't now how many lines will exist before the header, therefore, I cannot use `skiprows=4` as I did here.

I aware I can iterate through the file, as in the question [Read pandas dataframe from csv beginning with non-fix header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230083/read-pandas-dataframe-from-csv-beginning-with-non-fix-header).

What I am looking for is a simpler solution, like making `pandas.read_csv` disregard any empty line and taking the first non-empty line as the header.

Comment: Sorry but doesn't `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="|", comment="#")` work?

Comment: No, the comment lines are translated to empty lines, which are not disregarded.

Comment: Can it be a version issue? `skip_blank_lines=True` is the default in 0.18.1.

Comment: And when I ran your example with `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="|", comment="#")` it works exactly like you described in the desired output.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to set `skip_blank_lines=True`

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep="|", comment="#", skip_blank_lines=True).dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you. I suspected such an option should exist, and even check the read_csv help. I didn't find because I am using pandas 0.13. I will try to update.